# How to change the extention to all file in a directory using windows batch script

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, command-prompt

I need to change the file extensios of a directoy. If I do it manually so it will take more time. So is there any windows shell command or batch file to do this?
Like all .html file in a folder will be .php?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Take a look at the [`for` command](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and the [`~` modifiers](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of its variable...

Comment: can you please write that script here

Comment: Forget the `for` stuff, I was thinking too complicated and typing too quickly; the answers using `ren` will do it (`ren "*.htm*" "*.php"`); sorry for confusion...

Answer (score 2):

make a .bat in a folder and put in it this code

```
@ren *.Old_extension *.New_Extension
```

Also if you want to change more extensions just copy the lane and paste it under edited like this

```
@ren *.Old_extension *.New_Extension
@ren *.Old_extension2 *.New_Extension2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can easily do this Command Prompt
Suppose, You have a Folder  so many .TXT files in your folder.

Open that folder and just press SHIFT + RIGHT click and select Open Command Windows here

After that type the following command to change all .txt file to .doc

ren *.txt *.doc

It will change all text files in doc file
That's all